# How to randomize the size of faces on a mesh in three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, mesh

I recently started experimenting in three.js, and have been wondering if there is a way to randomize the size of the faces in a mesh created from one of their existing geometries.

Three.js is excellent for low-poly work, but the symmetry of the generated meshes ruin the effects somewhat-- I'm looking to find a way to give each face a slightly different size and perhaps jitter/rotation as well, to give it a more "handcrafted" look, so to speak.

I thought there might be a way to do it with math.random, but I'm a javascript newbie and am not sure how to go about using it.

This is the code for the object I want to give a less uniform appearance:

```
function createObject() {
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(70, 31, 17);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color:Colors.blue, 
        shading:THREE.FlatShading
    });
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    sphere.position.set(45,100,0);
    sphere.castShadow = true;
    sphere.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add(sphere);
}
```

Here's a fiddle with the rest of the code, but for whatever reason, although the code works locally, I can't get it to run in the browser. Still, it's there if you want to look at it. https://jsfiddle.net/redheadedmandy/f8fy4Lg8/1/

If anyone has a suggestion for how one might go about roughing up the uniformity of a three.js mesh, I would much appreciate it!

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what's the sacral point of using that revision of Three.js, which is outdated for several years (r71)? :)

Comment: I was looking for a cdn for the fiddle and didn't realize that it was an outdated version! The local file I was using is the most recent update.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Yes, thank you, it was exactly what I needed!

Comment: If so, mark the answer as accepted, please (the check mark under the vote counter of the answer) )

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the jsfiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/8x3nthc2/), based on yours. Well, mostly it's your example, just slightly modified, uses the latest version of Three.js.

As an option for "roughing", you can do it like that:

```
  var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(70, 31, 17);

  geometry.vertices.forEach(v => {
    v.x += THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(2);
    v.y += THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(2);
    v.z += THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(2);
  });

  geometry.computeFaceNormals(); // don't forget to do it, when you change vertices
```

Actually, there are many ways of how to change coordinates of vertices in a geometry. Creativity is up to you.

Comment: It took me a minute to figure out that the OP may just want to randomize vertices. I imagined taking the centroid of each face and then applying a random scale and was wondering what would that achieve :D

Comment: @pailhead If to be honest, it was my first thought too :D